# Get current user id in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

How do I Get the current user id in my controller using devise?

In my controller I have something like this:

```
def index

me = current_user
c = User.find(me)
@sheets = c.time_sheets
end
```

I am getting an error say that "Couldn't find User without an ID".

If If I put in a static number in the User.find() it works but of course that is not what I want.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks!

Comment: `@sheets = me.time_sheets`

Comment: Are you sure you are logged in? `User.find(current_user)` should reload the current user, not raise that error.

Comment: User.find(params[:id]); is what you may be looking for or even current user

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Replace current index action as below

```
def index    
   if current_user
     @sheets = current_user.time_sheets
   else
     redirect_to new_user_session_path, notice: 'You are not logged in.'
   end
end
```

If user is not logged in, i.e., current_user=nil then user would be redirected to login page with a flash message.

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!  That worked.  Was it not working before because devise could not determine if there was a a user logged in?

Comment: Glad to help.:) Devise would only set `current_user` upon login otherwise `current_user` would be nil.