# Ruby on Rails: Getting a route with Devise

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, mongoid

*TL;DR* How can I achieve this to always return routes with Devise User model ID in custom controllers (i.e. redirecting to `localhost:3000/profiles/504026426`) with Mongoid?

I have a project that has a social profile controller that returns of a user id with Devise but it will always complain that Mongoid needs a valid ID number in order to work with this route: `localhost:3000/profiles/`.

```
# Let's say I want to return a route with id (Devise) without having
# Rails to complain that Mongoid needs to a id of some number.

# So, I have controller containing profiles in the files.
# It goes like..
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
    # GET /profile/
    def index
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end
    # .. Snipped for brevity.
end
```

#### Is this the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the 'params[:id]' you're trying to find the user by won't work in the index view, because you're not passing in any parameter via the url ('profiles/:id' or: localhost:3000/profiles/504026426).  If you want to store a user to be available in the index view, use sessions and the current user helper method. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22106742/get-current-user-id-in-devise).

If you want your GET method to work with the 'params[:id]' it would look like:

```
get 'profile/:id' => 'profiles#show'
```

make sure it matches a show function in your controller

```
def show
  # this would work with: localhost:3000/profiles/504026426
     @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: Rails now complains that the template is missing. Reference code above is working for me. Though, it wants to mkdir `views/profile` according to the route.